# Increase values in map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map of key-value pairs. A priori I don't know it's size, i.e. how many and which keys I will have. Now, within a look, the keys "appear" and I need to increase the value for the corresponding key, each time it appears.

*Example:*

```
std::map<int, unsigned int> myMap;
std::vector<int> vectorOfValues; // 123,456,123,789,123,456
for(unsigned int i=0; i<vectorOfValues.size(); ++i) {
    myMap[vectorOfValues.at(i)] += 1;
}
```

So now `myMap` should contain `<123,3>, <456,2>, <789,1>`.

*Question:*

Is this the correct? I'm afraid the using the map without initialising the values isn't a good idea. But I'd like avoid to search for the entry each time I want to increase it.

Cheers!

Comment: As mentioned by others, can make it less verbose. myMap[vectorOfValues[i]]++; is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, it's fine, the `unsigned int` will be default constructed (i.e. zero initialized), one comment is that the `at()` call is superfluous - use the `operator[]` (as you already constrain by `size()`).

Answer (score 1):

This is correct; previously non-existing values will be initialized to zero.